# Jslint error: Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment

Tags: javascript, jslint

For this code:

```
var i = 0;
for (i < menuitem.length; i += 1;)
```

JSlint returns:

> Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment.
>
> Expected an identifier and instead saw ')'.

And refuses to continues scanning.
This code works fine but what is wrong? How could I write this with an "if" statement? (if that is what jslint means).

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: I'm not sure how your `for` loop works. It looks like it would be an infinite loop.

Comment: @minitech it runs trough a list of menu items. How should this be written then?

Comment: Your for loop is an infinite loop. JSlint is right in warning you. I think what you intended to write was: `for (;i < menuitem.length; i += 1)`. (check out where I moved the semicolon). Of course the more correct loop would be: `for (var i=0; i < menuitem.length; i += 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, JSLint is pretty vicious. As others have pointed out, you're not filling things in in the right places, but aside from that, JSLint requires that you put *something* in the initialization part of the `for` loop. There are a couple options you can do to make it play nice without messing with your logic, though. My favorite is to just reset `i` (even though it's already set):

```
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < menuitem.length; i += 1) {
    /** do stuff **/
}
```

This make JSLint happy and also ensures that `i` gets reset if you decide to use it for another `for` loop in the same lexical scope. Another option is to just toss a `null` in there to fill the space (if you don't want to reset the value of `i`):

```
var i = 0;
for (null; i < menuitem.length; i += 1) {
    /** do stuff **/
}
```

Both work fine and appease the ever-so-worrisome JSLint. However, no one will really care if you just leave the initialization part blank (aside from JSLint). You might try JSHint, as it's a bit more forgiving on this sort of thing.

Comment: No point setting `i=0` twice in a row like that. In my opinion, if `i` exists to be a `for` loop counter then its initial value is part of the logic that the `for` loop implements so it should be declared without an initial value as `var i;` and then initialised within the `for` with `for(i=0; ...`. (That should also pass JSLint.)

Comment: Agreed, @nnnnnn. I typically don't initialize `i` when I declare it in situations like this. However, it's possible the OP posted only relevant portions of his code and that `i` was used previously. It's not likely, but it's possible. No point in going after him about it only to be told I'm wrong because of some code that's not included. :-)

Comment: Yeah, cool. By the way, I didn't mean to be "going after" you about this.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop is kind of weird, the second part should be a condition for the loop, instead you have an assignment.

You must always have the parts in order `(initialisation; condition; step)`.

```
var i = 0;
for (; i < menuitem.length; i += 1)
```

I just moved your semicolon from the end to the start. Alternatively, you can place the variable declaration and assignment inside the first part if you like.

Comment: does not seem to pass validation unfortunately :(

Comment: @SnippetSpace did the validation message change? does it say the same thing?

Comment: @SnippetSpace: To pass validation it needs to be: `for (var i=0; i < menuitem.length; i += 1)`. The code above is still better than your original code though because even if it doesn't pass validation at least it works whereas your original code is obviously a bug.

Comment: original code worked too. just needed to pass validation to get past the error :)

Comment: @SnippetSpace: I don't really think the original code works the way you think it does because the test condition is always true in the original code at least until i rolls over back to 0 (do numbers roll over in javascript?)

Comment: @slebetman: No. Numbers do not roll over in JavaScript. They become `Infinity`. After a very long time, starting from 0...

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < menuitem.length; i += 1) {
  // code
}
```

Or

```
var i = 0;

for (; i < menuitem.length; i += 1) {
  // code
}
```

Comment: both don't seem to pass validation :(

Comment: loads. but figured it out, look at my response.

Answer (score 0):

From your code snippet, I'm going to assume that i is simply a variable used to control the number of cycles of your loop. The correct code would be

```
for (var i = 0; i < menuitem.length; i += 1) {
// code
}
```

That is the standardized declaration and syntax - at least for the languages I can think of right now. And that is really the point of this type of loop - for loops were designed this way so the author can simply write one line of code versus more if he/she wanted to do a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Here is the precise answer for validation:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < menuitem.length; i += 1) {
  // code
}
```

var should be outside says jslint :s

Comment: Nope, though it might be something else that JSLint doesn't like. What it's complaining about is the assignment `i += 1` appears where a condition is expected, which is probably `i < menuitem.length`.